# Variables in promises

Tags: javascript, variables, vue.js

I am very new to javascript and I am struggling to understand something.

I have this piece of code:

```
api.posts
  .browse({ limit: 5, include: 'tags,authors' })
  .then(posts => {
    posts.forEach(post => {
      console.log(post.title)
    })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
  })
```

This works fine and on the console I see the 5 post titles. However, I need to create a template with something like this:

```
<article v-for="post in posts" :key="post">
  <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
</article>
```

but of course "posts" is not accessible as a variable. I tried to add variables inside ".then" but with errors.
This might be a basic knowledge, but haven't been able to find a clear answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a variable / property outside the promise chain, then assign it the value when the promise is resolved. Generally, something like

```
api.posts
  .browse({ limit: 5, include: 'tags,authors' })
  .then(response => vm.data.posts = response)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. "vm" is not defined and also I'm not sure if "data" and "response" are variables or part of javascript, in this case.